# Cannot read property of undefined, directive *ngIf, Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm using this code to consume a service data and save it information in a variable:

```
dataUser: any;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    this.userService.getUserData(this.formPhotoProfile.value).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.dataUser = data;
    });
  }
```

When I use the variable 'dataUser' to get image value it work, the trouble is that when I use the variable with directive *ngIf appear this error: Cannot read property 'imageONE' of undefined

```
<img *ngIf="dataUser.imageONE" id="imagen-one" [src]="dataUser.imageONE">
```

[image]

Comment: try adding this: "dataUser?.imageONE" also as a good practice add it to a container like a div then the conditional and inside that div or ngContainer add the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this options (added an answer bc couldn't be able to edit the comment):

Opt1:

```
<div *ngIf="userData?.imageOne">
    <img [src]="userData?.imageOne"/>
</div>
```

Opt2:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userData?.imageOne">
    <img [src]="userData?.imageOne"/>
</ng-container>
```

Opt3:

```
<img [src]="userData?.imageOne"/>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4nubup